# Nutation frequency for a weighted gyroscope

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes, precession

So, I've been led to believe that the frequency of nutation of a gyroscope can be calculated using the formula

[image]

In which the I's are the moments of inertia around the principal axes and omega-3 is the angular velocity of the disk of the gyroscope. But the moments of inertia around the principal axes of a cilinder are

[image]

and working this out for a gyroscope with a disc of 1.5 kg, a radius of 11.5 cm and a height of 2,5 cm I get:

[image]

(There was a math error here, it's gone now) Which would mean the frequency of nutation is 2 times higher than the angular velocity, which does not match observation. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

[image]

The gyroscope used.

Comment: You have misunderstood the formula. The correct version relates the nutation and *precession* frequencies, not the angular velocity. Your interpretation of what the three moments of inertia are also seems to be wrong.

Comment: Could you perhaps direct me to some place where this is explained further? I got that formula from Morin's "Introduction to Classical Mechanics" and this is the best I can make of it.

Comment: The moments of inertia that you are currently using are the ones for the case of a body that is in *free fall*. The torque-free precession in free fall is with respect to the *center of mass of the body*. (The spinning disk in free fall case is also known as [Feynman's wobbling plate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVOcgFAoFv4), which indeed displays that ratio of 2:1) However, the picture of your setup shows a wheel mounted on an axis, and the pivot point is far away from the wheel. You need to use the moment of inertia of that *entire assembly*: wheel, axis and counterweight.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the nutation frequency is proportional to the *angular velocity* of the *spinning gyroscope*.

Article:
[precession and nutation of a gyroscope](http://butikov.faculty.ifmo.ru/Gyroscope.pdf), by Eugene Butikov
In the above article it is discussed that the nutation frequency is the same frequency as the frequency of [torque-free precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession#Torque-free) because it is in fact the torque-free precession. (The torque-free precession of the entire precessing assembly.)

Also:
Documentation for an educational set containing a gimbal mounted gyroscope and weights that can be added to the gimbal mounting, altering a specific moment of inertia, thus altering the nutation frequency:
[Laws of gyroscopes](https://www.nikhef.nl/~h73/kn1c/praktikum/phywe/LEP/Experim/1_3_20.pdf)

My understanding is that if the gyroscope wheel is mounted on a long axis that axis has a significant effect on the nutation frequency.